# VBA LIKE operator with string

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have this code:

```
Private Sub Item_AfterUpdate()
Me.SApp.Form.RecordSource = "SELECT * FROM Application WHERE Item = '" & Me.Item.Value & "';"
End Sub
```

Now , this works so it filters SApp (a subform) base on the value in the combobox Item.
I wanna do something similar however not with equal but with like.
So , something like:

```
Private Sub Item_AfterUpdate()
Me.SApp.Form.RecordSource = "SELECT * FROM Application WHERE Item LIKE '" & Me.Item.Value & "';"
End Sub
```

I tried :

```
'% Me.Item.Value %'

'% '" & Me.Item.Value & "' %'

'% s %' with (Dim s as string ; s = Me.Item.Value)
```

None of this solutions works , any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Does this `Me.SApp.Form.RecordSource = "SELECT * FROM Application WHERE Item LIKE '*" & Me.Item.Value & "*';"` help?

Comment: OK , IT works , you saved me thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the * wildcard in MsAccess, in other dbs it's usually %.

Ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208897(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: I tried putting * instead of % , but nothing. Looks like he's having problem identifiyng a string into a string (s inside the query string)